# need help using django-include-by-ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

so i tried to use django-include-by-ajax to load the page's main content first and then load the sidebar and navigation stuff when it's ready.

i followed the instructions here: https://github.com/archatas/django-include-by-ajax

but it didn't work, the page dosen't load until everything is ready (which takes some time because of multiple APIs) and the side bar dosen't even work

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load include_by_ajax_tags %}

{% block content %}

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app_name\css\style.css' %}">
```

```
  {% include_by_ajax "app_name/templates/sidebar.html" %}


  <div id="content" class="p-4 p-md-5 pt-5">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1" id="col1">
              <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                  <ul class="pagination">
                      <li class="page-item">
                          {% if pages.has_previous  %}
                          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ pages.next_page_number }}" aria-label="Next">
                              <span aria-hidden="true"><img src="{% static 'app_name/images/back.png' %}" width="50" height="50"></span></a>
                          {% endif %}
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </nav>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1" id="col2">
              {% for url in urllist %}
              <img src='{{ url }}' width="800" height="800"/>
              {% endfor %}
          </div>

          <div class="col-1" id="col3">
              <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                  <ul class="pagination">
                      <li class="page-item">
                          {% if pages.has_next %}
                          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ pages.previous_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous">
                              <span aria-hidden="true"><img src="{% static 'app_name/images/forward.png' %}" width="50" height="50"></span></a>
                          {% endif %}
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </nav>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

```
<script src="{% static 'app_name/JavaScript/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'app_name/JavaScript/popper.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'app_name/JavaScript/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'app_name/JavaScript/main.js' %}"></script>


{% endblock %}


{% block js %}
<script>
$(document).on('include_by_ajax_all_loaded', function() {
console.log('Now all placeholders are loaded and replaced with content');
})
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT**
i also tried

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load include_by_ajax_tags %}

{% block content %}

{% include "app_name/templates/main.html" %}
{% include_by_ajax "app_name/templates/sidebar.html" %}
  
    

{% endblock %}


{% block js %}
 <script>
 $(document).on('include_by_ajax_all_loaded', function() {
    console.log('Now all placeholders are loaded and replaced with content');
 })
 </script>
{% endblock %}
```